# Not able to use SwitchCompat in android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, switchcompat

We are trying to use **SwitchCompat** in our android application(**Eclipse**). We have taken the code and procedure from the below link.
[Material design](http://www.materialdoc.com/switch/)
When we created XML file for the same, we are getting the following error.

**The following classes could not be found: - android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)**

And we are not able to find any SwitchCompat class in android.support.v7.widget under "Android Private libraries"

[image: SwitchCompat.class]

**build.gradle**

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':appcompat_v7')
}

Your help in this regard is quite appreciable.

**SDK Manager screenshot**

[image]

**Errors---R.java not generating**
[image: R.java Not generating]

Comment: try latest `v7`  lib

Comment: go to sdkmanager. delete the android support lib and again download it.

Comment: I cannot see the option "Android Support library" in sdk manager to delete

Comment: i have attached the screenshot in my question

Comment: I have updated the file, now R.java is not generating and getting a lot of errors as shown in the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the support library. Then removed the duplicates under (res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-xhdpi, res/drawable-xxhdpi) and also under (bin/res/drawable-hdpi, bin/res/drawable-mdpi, bin/res/drawable-xhdpi, bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi). Updated all SDK build tools. Hope some one find it helpful.